# How to write Like statement that retrieve single and double quotes?

Tags: python, mysql

I have an encrypted column in the database table that include single and double quotes like this{`-"V'/L@AGL@*AWEO)&:'/(<RALROE*ARA"X$R}

```
  encryptedaName=encrypt(pName)   
  print(encryptedaName)  
  q=f"select * from laptop where Name like '%{encryptedaName}%'"
```

How can I write correct like statement to retrieve a string with single or double quotes?

Comment: Easy: use prepared statements.

Comment: @luk2302 How? Example please